# upper function not working for Latin-2 characters in KDB

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to run `upper` on a column that contains non-English characters: áéőí

```
q)t:([] nm: (`as;`$"áb"))
q)t
nm 
---
as 
áb
q)update upper_nm: upper nm from t
nm  upper_nm
------------
as  AS      
áb áB
```

I found a workaround using a system call to python but is much slower than the built-in function:

```
q)upper_py: {`$ system "python -c \"print(\\\"",string[x],"\\\".upper())\""}
q)update upper_nm: upper_py'[nm] from t
nm  upper_nm
------------
as  AS      
áb ÁB
```

There should be a nicer, faster way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any built-in `upper` function in Q which supports such characters.

The cleanest way to get it is to [bind it from .so](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/ffi/) But this approach is a bit of hassle

I would speed up you approach by passing list of string to python and parsing outcome to Q-list. This would prevent from calling system for every string:

```
t: ([] nm: (`as;`$"áb"));
toPythonList: {"[",("," sv "'",'x,'"'"),"]"};
pythonUpper: {system "python -c \"print([x.upper() for x in ",x,"])\""};
toQList: {-1_'1_'", " vs -1_1_x};
customUpper: {toQList first pythonUpper toPythonList x};
update upper_nm: customUpper string nm from t
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, my table has a few hundred thousand rows so a single system call fails with this amount of data. I settled with this function:

`ugly_upper:{[w] ssr[;"á";"Á"]ssr[;"é";"É"]ssr[;"í";"Í"]ssr[;"ó";"Ó"]ssr[;"ö";"Ö"]ssr[;"ő";"Ő"]ssr[;"ú";"Ú"]ssr[;"ü";"Ü"]ssr[;"ű";"Ű"] upper w}`

Comment: Great idea "@Gr3g CK". As you know your "special characters" map, I'd suggest to do this: `update nmu: {x^'("áéíóöőúüű"!"ÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰ")@/:x}upper string nm from t` instead of multiple `ssr`s. Should be faster, because chained `ssr`s will create lot of intermediate structures